# phonegap geolocation doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, geolocation

went according to this guide [Phonegap Geoloactaion](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation) and got this code eventually(android):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Device Properties Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
jQuery(window).ready(function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    });
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '          +                                   position.timestamp          + '<br />';
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
            'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and it's stuck on the "Finding geolocation..." message.
usually when apps want to use my location they ask to turn on GPS and you can see a little icon on the notification bar that clarifies that it turned on and searching for GPS but this doesn't seem to happen to my code.
**EDIT: I tried the geolocation.watchPosition Full Example and because it has a timeout it alerts me with a timeout, so I guess he tries to find my coords but fails too, Why is that? Maps and other nav app work fine**

Answer (score 4):

Did you put

`<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation" />`

on your `config.xml` file?

for more information on `config.xml` file in PhoneGap [check this page](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics)

Comment: it wasn't there, I have installed via console a couple of plugins and only 1 <feature... It didn't copy the src to files either for this pugin

Comment: is this the web config.xml or the config in the android app/res/xml config.xml?

Comment: @Adgezaza this is config for phonegap. for more information [link](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml)

Answer (score 3):

Are you testing on your Emulator ?

If yes, then you need to push the coordinates manually by going to Eclipse -> DDMS -> Emulator Control and send the location coordinates to the Emulator from there.

Also check if the Settings on your device have allowed the use of Location services.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.One day it worked and next day onwards it stopped working.When in restarted the phone it worked

Answer (score 1):

### When GPS works

In phonegap the application wont ask you to turn on gps, you have to implement this manually. Besides you can provide some options, e.g.

```
var config = {
   enableHighAccuracy: true,
   timeout: 20000,
   maximumAge: 18000000
}
```

So you error callback will now be triggered on timeout and when geolocation cannot determine your position. You should just debug your problem and see what the error callback returns.

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, config);
```

### When it does not work

In your case gps won't be fired. I cannot say really much regarding this problem because you only provided html5 code. One thing I could imagine is that you are missing the cordova.js file.

For better testing and debugging use Ripple emulator https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc

It emulates webapps and even has a geolocation mocker. This way you can debug your problem better because you can view the web console.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I have noticed that for GPS to work in phoneGap Apps, you need to "agree" to share your location with Google.

When I have disagreed before, the location would get timed out everytime.

Answer (score 0):

As you are loading jQuery remotely; can you verify whether it's loaded?
For example, if you put an alert() in the onload handler, does it show up?

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  jQuery(window).ready(function(){
    alert("jQuery ready");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
  });
}
```

If you don't see an alert message, you might have to check your 'res/xml/config.xml' to see if  the 'access origin' is set up correctly (e.g. using a wildcard)

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: it was like this <access origin=".*" /> so I changed it because it never already me for some reason, but the change didn't help :(

Comment: And did you add an alert as well, just to verify that the jQuery 'ready' event was fired?

Comment: yep, the alert was never fired, so i tried without the 'ready' event than the alert came though the geolocation still didn't work

Comment: Ok, and if you put an alert in the onDeviceReady handler? Could it be that that one isn't called either? (Are your sure that the path to the cordova js is correct?)

Comment: onDeviceReady alert fires(nav doesn't work), and ye i'm pretty sure. I even used their example app, still nothing